# Pass Woocomerce session data to databse or create custom cart data and passing it to db

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart

I need to add an expiry date to each product that are added to the cart and like to see it in order details after order is complete.

```
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($each_item[0],$each_item[1],'','',array('__expirydate',$d_expiry));
```

But the array, `array('__expirydate',$d_expiry)` i am passing is not showing with my cart. or adding with the woocommerce session.

So i set session manually using

```
WC()->session->set( 'expiry'.$each_item[0], $d_expiry );
```

And is working completely fine.But When Checkout that data is not stored anywhere.How to add it.

Answer (score 0):

The session is cleared when the order is completed. You probably need to save some meta information for the ordered item, which you can do via the `woocommerce_add_order_item_meta` hook.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'so_add_order_item_meta', 10, 3 );

    function so_add_order_item_meta( $order_item_id, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {

        if ( isset( $cart_item[ '__expirydate' ] ) && ! empty( $cart_item[ '__expirydate' ] ) ) {
            wc_add_order_item_meta( $order_item_id, __( 'Expiration date' ), $cart_item[ '__expirydate' ] );
        }
}
```

Keep in mind, this isn't a cut and paste solution, but a nudge down the right path.

Also, in lieu of your session approach you could probably look into using the following combination of filters: `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data`, `woocommerce_add_cart_item` and `woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session` to add data to the items in the cart (plus that would work with the code I've posted).

Good luck.

Comment: I used the `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` hook.But the session is still there.